# Resteasy security, oauth, android Client

Tags: security, rest, oauth, resteasy

I'm building an application which includes both server side components (resteasy) and an Android client.  In the Android client I'm making requests to the server using httpclient.

To log into Android client I want to use OAuth 2.0.

But what I'm the most concerned about is securing the server side.  Does anyone know how to secure the server side of my application?

Comment: What exactly are your concern about the server side?  What are you looking to secure?  Which clients can access it?  Security of data in transit/at rest?

Comment: Assuming you requested(using HttpClient) for server data from the URL: /rest/books, I want to make this request available only for the users who properly authenticated on the client with the OAuth.

Comment: REST APIs are usually accessed w/ username/password parameters.  The password doesn't necessarily have to be a password but could be some kind of code you give the Android client after you do OAuth verification on your server.